# show more & show less multiple text items is not working in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

show more and show less is not working properly , if i click on show more in induvial text it is working but if, I click on show more in one first text , after click on show more in second text the first text is collapsing instead of expanding the second plz help how to solve it i gave the code below plz check it

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [showStatus, setShowStatus] = useState(false);
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(0);

  const dummyData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      AbstractData:
        "The aim of this study was to determine in vitro the potential of Aloe Vera juice as a skin permeation enhancer;a secondary aim was to probe the extent to which Aloe Vera itself permeates the skin. Saturated solutions of caffeine, colchicine, mefenamic acid, oxybutynin, and quinine were prepared at 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin…"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
           
      AbstractData:
        "The aim of this study was to determine in vitro the potential of Aloe Vera juice as a skin permeation enhancer;a secondary aim was to probe the extent to which Aloe Vera itself permeates the skin. Saturated solutions of caffeine, colchicine, mefenamic acid, oxybutynin, and quinine were prepared at 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin…"
    },
    {
      id: 3,      
      
      AbstractData:
        "The aim of this study was to determine in vitro the potential of Aloe Vera juice as a skin permeation enhancer;a secondary aim was to probe the extent to which Aloe Vera itself permeates the skin. Saturated solutions of caffeine, colchicine, mefenamic acid, oxybutynin, and quinine were prepared at 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin…"
    }
  ];
  const handelShow = (id) => {
    setShowMore(id);
    setShowStatus(!showStatus);
  };
  return (
    <div className="abstract-card">
      {dummyData.map((result) => {
        const isTestOpen = result.id === showMore;
        return (
          <div key={result.id}>
            <div>             
              <div className="card-body pb-3 px-4 pt-3">
                <h6 className="fs-12 fw-bold mb-0 pb-2">Abstract</h6>
                <p className="mb-0 fw-normal text-color11">
                  {isTestOpen && showStatus
                    ? result.AbstractData
                    : result.AbstractData.substring(0, 300) + "..."}
                </p>
                <p
                  className="text-color5 fs-13 pt-2 mb-0"
                  onClick={() => handelShow(result.id)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "blue" }}
                >
                  {isTestOpen && showStatus ? "Show less..." : "Show more…"}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `state`s for handling just use `showMore`  state when the item `id` is equal to it, and remove the `showMore` state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(0);

  const dummyData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      AbstractData:
        "The aim of this study was to determine in vitro the potential of Aloe Vera juice as a skin permeation enhancer;a secondary aim was to probe the extent to which Aloe Vera itself permeates the skin. Saturated solutions of caffeine, colchicine, mefenamic acid, oxybutynin, and quinine were prepared at 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin…"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
           
      AbstractData:
        "The aim of this study was to determine in vitro the potential of Aloe Vera juice as a skin permeation enhancer;a secondary aim was to probe the extent to which Aloe Vera itself permeates the skin. Saturated solutions of caffeine, colchicine, mefenamic acid, oxybutynin, and quinine were prepared at 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin…"
    },
    {
      id: 3,      
      
      AbstractData:
        "The aim of this study was to determine in vitro the potential of Aloe Vera juice as a skin permeation enhancer;a secondary aim was to probe the extent to which Aloe Vera itself permeates the skin. Saturated solutions of caffeine, colchicine, mefenamic acid, oxybutynin, and quinine were prepared at 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin…"
    }
  ];
  const handelShow = (id) => {
    setShowMore(id);
  };
  return (
    <div className="abstract-card">
      {dummyData.map((result) => {
        const isTestOpen = result.id === showMore;
        return (
          <div key={result.id}>
            <div>             
              <div className="card-body pb-3 px-4 pt-3">
                <h6 className="fs-12 fw-bold mb-0 pb-2">Abstract</h6>
                <p className="mb-0 fw-normal text-color11">
                  {isTestOpen
                    ? result.AbstractData
                    : result.AbstractData.substring(0, 300) + "..."}
                </p>
                {isTestOpen ? <p
                  className="text-color5 fs-13 pt-2 mb-0"
                  onClick={() => handelShow(0)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "blue" }}
                >
                   "Show less..." 
                </p> : <p
                  className="text-color5 fs-13 pt-2 mb-0"
                  onClick={() => handelShow(result.id)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "blue" }}
                >
                   "Show more..." 
                </p> }
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit react-read-more-read-less (forked)]

Comment: it is working for show more only not working if i click on snow less .i need  like toggle if i click show more it has to show more and turn the button show less thank you!

Comment: sorry now it is not working please check and make it work  thanks https://codesandbox.io/s/react-read-more-read-less-forked-lz3odc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Harshan, Yes, just forgot to switch the click handlers, I just update the answer with codesandbox, please check again.